# I am confused about the past participle

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives, past-participles

I want to know what type of sentence the sentence below is and why we use two past participles in it.I took this sentence from a chemistry book; chemistry is my subject.

1) Concentration of CO2 and water vapour absorb infrared radiation emitted by earth surface.

Comment: Look up *infrared* in a dictionary: it's not a participle, *infrare* + *-d* but an adjective/color name, *infra* + *red*, like *ultraviolet*.

Comment: The sentence works in the same way as saying: *... radiation **which is emitted** by earth surface*. It's a participle clause.

Answer (score 2):

In English there are many irregular verbs (Ex: 'to see' is an irregular verbs: the past is 'I saw' not 'I seed').

'Infrared' isn't a verb at all. 'Infrared' is 'infra' + 'red'.

'Emit' uses rules for regular verbs (verbs + ed) and we can divide 'emitted' into 'emit' (verb in present form) + 'ed'. Using this rule it should be 'emited', but in English when there is a consonant you have to double it and the full word becomes 'emitted'.

If you want look at some other forms of the verb to 'emit', you can look [here](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/emit)